# What to report in a time serie database when the measure failed?

Tags: time-series

I use a time series database to report some network metrics, such as the download time or DNS lookup time for some endpoints. However, sometimes the measure fails like if the endpoint is down, or if there is a network issue. In theses cases, what should be done according to the best practices? Should I report an impossible value, like `-1`, or just not write anything at all in the database?

The problem I see when not writing anything, is that I cannot know if my test is not running anymore, or if it is a problem with the endpoint/network.

Comment: I don’t know if this is applicable to your problem. But if you have such a situation in Swift, you can set the unknown value simply to `nil`, meaning there is no valid value (I tried it but there was no valid response). The same can of course be done in other cases if some of the possible values are set to a special meaning, like -1, as long as it is clear what this special value means.

Comment: If you find that you will have multiple different issues/problems then the best practice I have seen is to create a quality flag mask. You can store it as 1 byte, where each of the 8 bits (2^8 = 256) can represent some quality. So 1, or 00000001 could be OK, and anything above 200 could be your error codes. So 11001000+ could be all various error codes like - process ran but value x was missing, etc. You can set ranges in your documentation for what each range could be i.e. network vs hardware.  Then store this byte and you have an easily stored (space) and highly detailed (up to 256 values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to capture the failures in their own time series for separate analysis.

Failures or bad readings will skew the series, so they should be filtered out or replaced with a projected value for 'normal' events.  The beauty of a time series is that one measure (time) is globally common, so it is easy to project between two known points when one is missing.

The failure information is also important, as it is an early indicator to issues or outages on your target.  You can record the network error and other diagnostic information to find trends and ensure it is the client and not your server having the issue.  Further, there can be several instances deployed to monitor the same target so that they cancel each other's noise.

You can also monitor a known endpoint like [google's 204 page](http://clients1.google.com/generate_204) to ensure network connectivity.  If all the monitors report an error connecting to your site but not to the known endpoint, your server is indeed down.